# How can I open an excel file once the program finishes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwt

How can I have the excel workbook automatically open once the program completes? Not actually opening the file within the program to read, edit, etc. Open and run the actual excel file.

```
    for x in os.listdir():
        if x = 'lastfileindirectory':
            workbook.save('excel.xls')
            Then open 'excel.xls'
            break
```

Comment: sorry for the horrible formatting. Obviously everything below the if statement is meant to be indented.

Comment: you know yhat you can edit your question in order to fix any formatting errors?

I fixed the indentation for you

Comment: you might specify whether you're running under windows (which version) or on any other os.
This will have an impact on the correct answer

Comment: You mean, like, *cause Microsoft Excel to start up* and have the workbook displayed in that program? (or perhaps some other program, such as LibreOffice Calc?)

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify. Still very new to coding. Operating on Windows 10. My program is in python and uses XLWT to write to an excel file. I'd like to have that excel open once the program is complete. Exactly what Karl said, cause Excel to start up. I found this on another similar question: os.system("open -a 'path/Microsoft Excel.app' 'path/file.xlsx'")